# Kafka consumer cannot consumer from external Kafka server

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have Zookeeper and Kafka running in a physical server and I have build a docker container running an java application to connect to the external Kafka as consumer.

Kafka listening port:

```
[helio@dev-01 kafka]$ netstat -an|grep 9092
tcp6       0      0 :::9092                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I'm using docker shared network, but the consumer application is not able to connect to the kafka.
I can see I can reach the kafka IP from inside of the container... I tried a simple to see that I can reach kafka server from the network:

at Container:

```
root@ff419d41540a:~# ssh -p 9092 192.168.1.251
```

at Kafka log I can see the test connection:

```
[2018-05-21 12:33:39,093] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=0] Unexpected error from /172.17.0.2; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1397966893 larger than 104857600)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:132)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:235)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:196)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:557)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:495)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:424)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:628)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

so,is there any limitation on this? Some port value limitation?

If I start the Consumer Docker container with --network=host (host network) then the consumer application is able to connect to Kafka and works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could enable more logs on Kafka consumer library so I could figure out the issue.
Even using the IP:Port to define the Kafka server as showing in the log:

```
16:34:04.670 [main] INFO  o.a.k.c.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig     values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [192.168.1.251:9092]
```

but another kafka consumer log has showed that it's getting the hostname (Physical server) and once the container cannot resolve that name, the consumer fails:

```
16:34:08.861 [Consumer] INFO  o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=messageRouterConsumer] Group coordinator dev-01:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
```

So I could work around this issue adding the kafka hostname server into container /etc/hosts:

```
echo "192.168.1.251   dev-01" >> /etc/hosts
```

And then the Kafka Consumer application inside of a container started to consume from the topic.